# Laravel app dir missing from generator path

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Just switched over to work on a project and create a new migration using the Way/Generators package command `php artisan generate:migration`

When I do, I get this error:

```
[ErrorException]
file_put_contents(/path/to/site/laravel/database/migrations/2014_09_02_145128_create_templates_table.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Looking at the path it is clear why it failed...it should be `/laravel/app/database/`. Checking the `paths.php` file I see that nothing has changed.

So far I am unable to locate the change (not a git project so no log).

Where could this path mistake have occurred in the Laravel configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Laravel 4.3 (or dev-master) directories changed drastically and migrations was moved to that particular place. Check your composer json and pull "laravel/framework": "4.2.*".

Comment: That was the problem! Laravel 4.2.* already set, but I needed to roll back to `"way/generators": "~2.0"`. Thanks! :)